# TypeError: something.changeBy is not a function

Tags: javascript

Examine this code:

```
var something = (function() {
    var countit = 0;

    function changeBy(val) {
        countit += val;
    }

    return {
        inc: function () {
            changeBy(1);
        },
        value: function () {
            return countit;
        }
    };
})();

console.log(something.value());
something.inc();
console.log(something.value());
something.changeBy(2);
console.log(something.value());
```

The thing is, the `something.changeBy(2);` isn't working. It says it's not a function:

```
TypeError: something.changeBy is not a function
```

I, of course understand by this fact, that it has something to do with the `return`, but I just don't get it why is that so and obviously would like you to explain me this.

Comment: something doesn't have a `changeBy` method, because you aren't returning it in the returned object - add `, changeBy: changeBy` before `};`

Answer (score 0):

you haven't expose `changeBy` method. add property `changeBy` ref the origin function.

```
var something = (function() {
var countit = 0;

function changeBy(val) {
    countit += val;
}

return {
    changeBy:changeBy,
    inc: function () {
        changeBy(1);
    },
    value: function () {
        return countit;
    }
};
})();
```